# wpf events and chain of responsibility pattern

Tags: wpf, chain-of-responsibility

do routed events from wpf have something in common with the chain of responsibility pattern ?

i googled for this and i don't see anyone talking about this :S, although i though that the routed events are an implementation of that pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i guess it is so, the routed events in wpf are an implementation of the chain of responsibility pattern